# Integral substitution isn't working for some reason?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to evaluate this integral

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{4+3\sin\theta}d\theta$$

The substitution that I tried making was $z=e^{i\theta}$

I know that

$$\sin\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$

This means that

$$\sin\theta= \frac{1}{2i}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

$$d\theta =\frac{dz}{iz}$$

When I plug it into the integral what I get is

$$\int_{C}\frac{1}{4+\frac{3}{2i}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)}\frac{dz}{iz}$$

Where $C$ is the unit circle oriented positively.

When I multiply this out what I get is

$$\int_{C}\frac{1}{4iz + 1.5z^{2} - 1.5}dz$$

Now I'm stuck. I simply don't know how to evaluate this integral. I was wondering what I need to do to be able to finish this integral?

Comment: Find the pole(s) inside $C$ and compute the residue of the integrand at each one?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks a lot I think I know how to do this now.

Comment: This is not substitution rather contour integration.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let$$f (\theta)=\frac{1}{4+3\sin(\theta)}. $$
put
$$t=\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}} $$

and replace

$\sin (\theta) $ by

$$\frac{2t}{1+t^2} $$

and
$d\theta $ by

$$\frac {2dt}{1+t^2} $$

to get a rational fraction.

OBSERVE THAT

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f (\theta)d\theta=2\int_0^\pi f (\theta)d\theta $$

you will get

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac {2dt}{2t^2+3t+2} $$

Comment: now in the Moment i just deleted my post with the same answer

Comment: I should've specified in the question, but I'm trying to do this question using that specific substitution that I posted.